# Angular 2 Routing issue, No Output

Tags: angular, routes

I am Learning Angular and am fairly new. I'm currently working on a project and just finished setting up my routing but now I am not able to see any of the content on the web page that I was able to before when the content was located in the app.component.html file.

It was then moved to a template in the buttons.component.ts file.

Can someone please tell me why there is no output?

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

const routes: Routes= [
  {path: 'demo', loadChildren: './demo/demo.module#DemoModule'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'demo'}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---- demo.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MaterialModule } from '../shared/material.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DemoRoutingModule } from './demo-routing.module';
import { ButtonsComponent } from './buttons/buttons.component';
import { FlexboxComponent } from './flexbox/flexbox.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DemoRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [ButtonsComponent, FlexboxComponent]
})
export class DemoModule { }
```

---- demo.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ButtonsComponent} from './buttons/buttons.component';
import {FlexboxComponent} from './flexbox/flexbox.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'buttons', component: ButtonsComponent},
    {path: 'flexbox', component: FlexboxComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'buttons'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DemoRoutingModule { }
```

----- buttons.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons',
  template: `
  <button mat-button>
     <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>  
     Click me!
  </button>
<mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ButtonsComponent {

}
```

Comment: I've stared at this for quite a while, compared it against another project... and I can't spot any errors in the setup - but maybe I'm blind. Only thing I don't see is, did you remember to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app.component.html file?

Comment: add your app.component.ts and html file here